# Performance problem when getting text from a context node with VTD-XML

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have a structure like this:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>foo</c>
    <d>bar</d>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c>baz</c>
    <d>qux</d>
  </b>
</a>
```

I set `/a/b` as context and loop through all occurrences to get the texts of `c` and `d`:

```
VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
vg.parseFile("test.xml", true);

VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();

AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);

ap.selectXPath("/a/b");

while(ap.evalXPath() != -1) {
  String c = extractText(vn, "c");
  String d = extractText(vn, "d");
}
```

Currently, I use the `extractText()` method I've written to extract the texts of the nodes inside the loop:

```
public String extractText(VTDNav v, String path) throws Exception {
  VTDNav vn = v.cloneNav();
  AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);

  ap.selectXPath(path);

  int elementIndex = ap.evalXPath();

  if(elementIndex == -1) {
    return null;
  }

  int tokenIndex = (path.contains("@"))
                    ? vn.getAttrVal(vn.toString(elementIndex))
                    : vn.getText();

  return (tokenIndex == -1) ? null : vn.toString(tokenIndex);
}
```

In the method, I clone the `VTDNav` and create a new `AutoPilot` instance **so I don't displace the cursor of those objects of my loop** when selecting the new XPath.

Furthermore, I have to check the `path` whether it contains an `@`, to see if it's an text node or an attribute (i.e. to use `getText()` or `getAttrVal()`).

My profiler shows that my `extractText()` method takes the most time in my huge application, so there must be a better solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution, which doesn't improve the performance, but is a lot shorter. I didn't know about the `evalXPathToString()` method.

```
protected String extractText(VTDNav v, String path) throws Exception {
  AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(v);
  ap.selectXPath(path);
  return ap.evalXPathToString();
}
```

Furthermore, the check in my old version whether the path contains a `@` was buggy. It returned `true` for a path like `/a[@b='c']` and executed `getAttrVal()` for it, which is wrong.

Comment: Did u put this function in a loop?

Comment: Yes, please take a look at my first code block in the question. I use this function within the `while`-loop.

Comment: Take xpath compilation out of loop especially when your XML is small.